# How to convert a Set<Set> to an ArrayList<ArrayList>

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

How would I add all the elements of a `Set<<Set<String>>` var to an `ArrayList<<ArrayList<String>>`? Of course I'm aware of the naive approach of just adding them.

```
 private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> groupAnagrams(ArrayList<String> words){
              ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> groupedAnagrams = new ArrayList<>();
              AbstractMap<String, String> sortedWords = new HashMap<>();
              Set<Set<String>> sameAnagramsSet = new HashSet<>();
              for(String word : words){
                  char[] wordToSort = word.toCharArray();
                  Arrays.sort(wordToSort);
                  sortedWords.put(word, new String(wordToSort));
              }
              for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: sortedWords.entrySet() ){
                  Set<String> sameAnagrams = new HashSet<>();
                  sameAnagrams.add(entry.getKey());
                  for(Map.Entry<String, String> toCompare : sortedWords.entrySet()){
                      if(entry.getValue().equals(toCompare.getValue())){
                          sameAnagrams.add(toCompare.getKey());
                      }
                  }
                  if(sameAnagrams.size()>0){
                      sameAnagramsSet.add(sameAnagrams);
                  }
              }

            //-->this line does not work!  return new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(sameAnagramsSet);

          }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the 'naive' approach of just adding them that you find it unacceptable?

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum I figured there would be a better way, especially with the advent of Java 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Java 8, you can do:

```
return sameAnagramsSet.stream()
       .map(ArrayList::new)
       .collect(toList());
```

although it returns a `List<ArrayList<String>>`.

What it does:

- `.stream()` returns a `Stream<Set<String>>`
- `.map(ArrayList::new)` is equivalent to `.map(set -> new ArrayList(set))` and basically replaces each set by an array list
- `collect(toList())` places all the newly created lists in one list

Comment: I do love a good Java 8 answer. Can you explain this code, because I imagine a lot of people (including myself) don't know too much about Java 8 just yet.

Comment: @assylias that's what I was looking for; mind explaining what it does?

Comment: @assylias I don't follow. I know the cons operator divides the list(like in OCaml), but I have no clue what you are doing there.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to convert each element from a `Set` to an `ArrayList`, you'll have to do at least a little of this with an explicit loop, I think (unless you're using Java 8 or a third-party library):

```
Set<Set<String>> data = . . .

ArrayList<List<String>> transformed = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for (Set<String> item : data) {
    transformed.add(new ArrayList<String>(item));
}
```

Note that I changed the type of the transformed list from `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` to `ArrayList<List<String>>`. Generally it's preferable to [program to an interface](http://www.fatagnus.com/program-to-an-interface-not-an-implementation/), but if you really need a list that must contain specifically instances of `ArrayList`, you can switch it back.

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing that, I figured that much out, but I figured I could use a functional programming hack with Java 8 to do it.

Comment: OP wanted an `ArrayList<ArrayList>`, but an `ArrayList<List>` is not the same.

Comment: @DavidWallace - No, I suppose not. Not that it makes much difference to OP since he evidently didn't want to use this approach.

Comment: Yes, but this answer is useful to those who either (i) are still using Java 6 or 7, or (ii) would prefer code that is easier to read and maintain.  I find the Java 8 answer quite a bit harder to understand, so speaking as a professional programmer, I would always prefer to use something like this.

Comment: @DavidWallace - Good point. I left the changed type but added a note explaining why and what to do if it would create a problem.